# android studi, non-latin chars appear as ???? in webservice

Tags: android, encoding

I am calling webservice from within my anroid app
it works fine except when send non-latin text (Arabic)
it reaches the service as ???????

I debugged the app and I can see the arabic text clear in the body before calling the service
Not sure if there is a coding format somewhere need to be changed or what?

```
   body.setInsertMsgRequestData(data);
    envelope.setInsertMsgRequestBody(body);
    return envelope;
```

body on debug is this

[image]

Comment: Try checking the encoding on the server what are you using for the service?

Comment: @Hugosama how to check that?? any instructions?

Comment: I need to know on which technology is your webservice made

Comment: @Hugosama i used C#.net

Comment: I called the webservice from another .net application it works perfectly, the problem is only exist when i call the service from the Android App